# unclosed quotation mark error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error as

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '192''. Incorrect
>   syntax near '192''

I have checked my Query many times and I am not able to spot the error.

my code snippet looks like this :-

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {   

            string catid = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
            Query = "select * from messages where messageid ='" + catid + "'";
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            Repeater2.DataSource = ds;
            Repeater2.DataBind();

        }
```

Please help..

Comment: You shouldn't be generating your queries by concatting strings together.  This error message is an excellent explanation as to why.  SQL code can be injected into your query by the user's data.  You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: @Servy - Post that as an answer with the correct formatting/escaping solution

Comment: The error message tells you the problem `'192''`. There are 3 `'`.  `catid == "192'"`.  A simple debug of your code would of told you everything you need to know

Comment: I suggest you read [How to trace and debug in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

Comment: I suggest that you look into parametrizing SQL queries

Comment: Parameterized queries is the only safe method for building "dynamic" SQL.

Comment: @CameronTinker even then you have to be careful, depending on what you do with the parameter in your stored proc. I've seen code like: `declare @sql nvarchar(4000) set @sql = 'select * from table where id = ' + @fooparam + '; exec sp_executesql @sql`. Which completely circumnavigates all of the benefits parameterized queries give you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using parametrize query, it will avoids errors . In your case you should not be quoting the `id` and also you are exposed to SQL injection.

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
    string conString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "select * from messages where messageid =@catid",
        con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", catid);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
              //get the data
            } 
        }
    }
}
```